# Error in select all/ unselect all checkboxes code wxpython

Tags: wxpython

Hi I am trying to implement a GUI where selecting/unselecting 1 check box titled "ALL" will select/unselect the rest of the checkboxes. However this code does not work and i cant seem to find out why. Here is my code:

```
import wx
import calendar,datetime
import os

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "", size = (500, 800))
    panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

    labelGetTime = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Select Time Duration")
    labelGetArea = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Select Area")
    labelStart = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Start")
    self.startCal = wx.DatePickerCtrl(panel, style=wx.DP_DROPDOWN | wx.DP_SHOWCENTURY)
    labelEnd = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "End")
    self.endCal = wx.DatePickerCtrl(panel, style=wx.DP_DROPDOWN | wx.DP_SHOWCENTURY)
    retrieveBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Retrieve Data")
    getStatBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Get Statistics")
    getGraphBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Plot Graph")
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClickGetDay, retrieveBtn)
    #self.Bind(panel, self.OnSet, getStatBtn)
    #self.Bind(panel, self.OnSet, getGraphBtn)



    self.cb_list = []
    self.selAllCB = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "ALL")
    self.cb_list.append(wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "Area1"))
    self.cb_list.append(wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "Area2"))
    self.cb_list.append(wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "Area3"))
    self.cb_list.append(wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "Area4"))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnSelect, self.selAllCB)

    box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    timeBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    areaBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    getTimeBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    getAreaBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    btnBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    staBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    endBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    box.Add(labelGetTime, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5)
    box.Add(timeBox, 4, wx.ALL, 5)
    box.Add(labelGetArea, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5)
    box.Add(areaBox, 6, wx.ALL, 5)

    timeBox.Add(getTimeBox, 3, wx.ALL, 5)
    timeBox.Add(retrieveBtn, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    areaBox.Add(getAreaBox, 3, wx.ALL, 5)
    areaBox.Add(btnBox, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

    getTimeBox.Add(staBox, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    getTimeBox.Add(endBox, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    getAreaBox.Add(self.selAllCB, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    getAreaBox.Add(self.cb_list[0], 1,wx.ALL| wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    getAreaBox.Add(self.cb_list[1], 1,wx.ALL| wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    getAreaBox.Add(self.cb_list[2], 1,wx.ALL| wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    getAreaBox.Add(self.cb_list[3], 1,wx.ALL| wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    btnBox.Add(getStatBtn, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.BOTTOM , 8)
    btnBox.Add(getGraphBtn, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP, 8)
    staBox.Add(labelStart, 1, wx.ALL, 5)
    staBox.Add(self.startCal, 4, wx.ALL)
    endBox.Add(labelEnd, 1, wx.ALL, 5)
    endBox.Add(self.endCal, 4, wx.ALL)

    panel.SetSizer(box)
    box.Fit(self)


def OnSelect(self):
    for cb in self.cb_list:
        cb.SetValue(self.selAllCB.GetValue())


class MyApp(wx.App):
def OnInit(self): #wxWindows calls this method to initialize the application
    frame = MainFrame(None, -1) #Create an instance of MainFrame class
    frame.Show()

    self.SetTopWindow(frame)    #Tell wxWindows that this is main window
    return True                 #Success flag

app = MyApp()  
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OnSelect(self) should be:

```
def OnSelect(self, evt):
```

You should always read the output of your program on the console.